# How do I run code on exiting a Vorpal.js app?

Tags: javascript, vorpal.js

I'm writing a vorpal.js app that loads a file on launch, and should write a modified version of the file on exit. How do I run code on exit? Is there some place I can attach a callback or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hook to the [node.js process exit event](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit).

```
process.on('exit', (code) => {
    // Do some cleanup here
    console.log(`About to exit with code: ${code}`);
});

const vorpal = require('vorpal')();

vorpal
  .delimiter('myapp$')
  .show();
```

Comment: So... if I want to show the user a "are you sure you want to exit?" message, does that mean there's no way to do that? By the time node's exit hook runs, Vorpal will already be gone.